# "I'm know" is correct?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

I saw using "I'm know" in formal communications with native speakers. Does that sound right?

I found quite a few instances among books in Google search results.

The context:
"I’m know you will be a great addition"

Disclaimer: I have already checked with spell-checker tools and it was wrong according to Grammarly.

Comment: I know. I'm know does not mean anything in English. There are many grammar checkers online. Please try to post some research with your question or show, beyond just googling, why you think something is right or wrong.

Comment: Certainly "I'm know" is not standard English.

Comment: I could only find typos where it should obviously be "I know", an album name, and this question, when I googled "I'm know"

Comment: "I'm" means "I am". Does "I am know" make sense to you?

Comment: It is most likely a typo. They are *extremely* common.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your usage is incorrect.

If you mean that you are aware of something, or understand something, then "I know" is correct, and "I'm know" is incorrect.  The following examples are correct:

> I know that you will be a great addition to the team.
>   I am confident that you will be a great addition to the team.

If you mean that other people know you, then "I'm known" is correct, and "I'm know" is incorrect.  The following examples are correct:

> I'm known as Jasper on this website.
>   I'm known for a math project I did a while back.

"I'm known" is less formal than "I am known".  Contractions are rarely used in formal communications.

Answer (score 5):

"I'm know" is definitely incorrect. A Google search shows it's mostly used by non-native speakers, especially Spanish and Russian native speakers. It also comes up as the title of one or two songs.

Breaking the contraction down, you have "I am know." Both "am" and "know" are verbs, and neither are used as "helping" verbs. Only one of the verbs should be applicable:

> I **know**. (This means that I understand the topic)
>
> I **am** knowledgeable. (This means that I generally understand or know about many different things)

Comment: "am" is used as a helping verb with gerunds, e.g. "I am going".

Comment: @Barmar true, but "I am knowing you will be a great addition" isn't English, even though one can guess what it means. (And I don't think this is a gerund - it's just the present continuous form of the verb).

Comment: True, I was just addressing the general point you made. Progressive mode can't be used with all verbs.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's true. I just noted that neither were being used as helping verbs in the sentence (not that _know_ is ever used as a helping verb), as I didn't want to muddle the issue explaining what a helping verb is and how it's used.